# How to search using backslash

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working to look through websites to find specific words. I use the re.compile with bs4 to search for the word. I am having issues if my word contains a backslash ('\'). I was hoping I could get some help on how to do this. My code is usually like this

```
results = self.soup.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word), re.IGNORECASE), recursive=True)
```

This code throws an error of `re.error: bad escape \M at position 13` when I try to have `searched_word = Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

I read somewhere that in order to escape backslash, I should make it `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` which throws an error. Or `Software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Run` which doesn't throw an error but does not return the text.

Comment: use `re.escape()`? https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: I write answer then and you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not escaping the string for `re.compile()`. To do that, use `re.escape()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.escape)):

```
results = self.soup.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(re.escape(searched_word)), re.IGNORECASE), recursive=True)
```